# how to check one var in list? and not in list

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following array.

```
$ar = array("apple:3","banana:2","canopule:6","grapes:5","cherry:8");
```

How can I check to see if the following variable

```
$a = "grapes";
```

Is in the array (in this case `grapes:5`) and if it is, return the matched string. I.e., "grapes : 5"

If it's not in the list (e.g., matching "strawberry"), return "strawberry : not found."

I have this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($ar); $i++) {
    list($name,$count)=explode(":",$ar[$i]);
    if($a==$name)
        echo "$a : $count";
    else
        echo "$a : not found!";
}
```

If it matches, it works fine. But if not, I get

> strawberry : not found!strawberry : not found!strawberry : not found!strawberry : not found!strawberry : not found!

It returns every false case instead of just one.

Comment: Do you have to have the data in array like this? Could you not use an associative array for this like array('apple' => 3, 'banana' => 2, ...) as it would make your code much nicer...

Comment: no, i dont have data like this, just example

Comment: Quick Question would you every have instance where your list looks like this `array("apple:3","banana:2","canopule:6","grapes:5","cherry:8","banana:10");` .. duplicate fruit but different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$ar=array("apple:3","banana:2","canopule:6","grapes:5","cherry:8");
$a = "strawberry";
$result = '';
for($i=0;$i<count($ar);$i++){
    list($name,$count)=explode(":",$ar[$i]);
    if($a == $name){
        $result = "$a : $count";
        break;
    }
}

if($result){
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo $a." : Not found";
}
```

Simply check if there is something in loop if yes print result, if no add not found.

Comment: Break out of the loop when result is found?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are not pushed to use array like this and you are asking for educational purpose then try the associative array: then the code looks very simple:

```
$ar = array("apple" => 3,"banana" => 2,"canopule" => 6,"grapes" => 5,"cherry" => 8);
$a = "grapes";

echo isset($ar[$a]) ? "$a : ".$ar[$a] : "$a : not found";
```

I know that you were not asking exactly about this but I wanted to say that sometimes it is simpler to think of way of storing the data rather than coming up with new algorithms.

Comment: thks for ur suggestion, i store data in a txt file, each line of the file for each directory and its contents ( more than 6 info ), split by \t

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `foreach` and `substr`.

```
$ar = array("apple:3","banana:2","canopule:6","grapes:5","cherry:8");
$a = "cherry";    
$result = $a . ": not found";

foreach ($ar as $fruit) {
    if (substr($fruit,0,strpos($fruit,":")) == $a) {
        $result = $a . ": " . substr($fruit,strpos($fruit,":") + 1);
        break;
    } 
}

echo $result;
```

`foreach` iterates over every element in the array (may also be used like `foreach ($ar as $num => $fruit)` for distinguishing between keys and values). Using `substr` instead of `explode` is just for illustrating another way to split up composite values like yours. Looking for the occurence of the colon, the string is split up by using chars from the beginning to n for run1 which extracts the fruit name, and chars n+1 to the end for run2 which extracts the count value. Remember that the index for characters within a string start at position 0.

Comment: Some edits. Sorry for a "quick shot". Now it should be clearer and correct. Feel free to ask or improve!